# uncaughtExceptions to send statistics

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, statistics

My application (in NodeJS) is collecting user statistics. The last step in this process is sending these collected user statistics using REST. Because this step is final, whenever there's an error during the applications process, no statistics will be send. I want to add the error message to the statistics and send it.

In NodeJS there's an event `UncaughtExeption`, is it safe to use this event to send user statistics whenever an uncaught error occurs? Or is this a wrong approach for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to send off your statistics after an uncaught exception, as long as you exit the process afterwards. Resuming the process is dangerous since the application is in an unknown state.

I would suggest doing something like below:

```
function sendStatistics() {
    // Send your stats via REST or whatever.
    console.log("sendStatistics: Sending statistics..")
}

process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
    // Should log exceptions here too.
    console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');

    sendStatistics()

    // We must exit since the process is in an unknown state.
    process.exit(1);
});
```

The Node.js documentation on [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) explains a lot, including how to use the event correctly.

Specifically:

The correct use of 'uncaughtException' is to perform synchronous cleanup of allocated resources (e.g. file descriptors, handles, etc) before shutting down the process. **It is not safe to resume normal operation after 'uncaughtException'.**

I think you can look at sending the statistics as part of cleanup since this is a vital task.